# Split an arithmetic expression with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex, arithmetic-expressions

I want to split an expression like `-1*-0.8/5-5` into `[ '-1', '*', '-0.8', '/', '5', '-', '5' ]`

`[ '-1', '*', '-0.8', '/', '5-5' ]` This is what I'm getting right now with `expression.split(/([*/])/g);`

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Perhaps, `/([*/]|\b-)/`. Your regex does not work with parentheses and `+` and the `/([*/]|\b-)/` won't work with them either.

Comment: *I want to split an expression* No, what you want to do is **parse** (or perhaps **lexically analyze**) an expression. For that, unsurprisingly, you should use a parser, or a lexical analyzer. Or, you could use any of a number of competent packages out there that parse/evaluate arithmetic expressions for a living.

Comment: Did [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43801821/4927984) solved your issue?

Comment: Yes, but I went with /(\b[*/+-])/ eventually, the spaces were pre-eliminated @Mistalis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution. It correctly detects `+`, `-`, `/`, `*` and accept the use of whitespaces:

```
([*\/]|\b\s*-|\b\s*\+)
```

```js
var expression = "-1*-0.8/5-5";
console.log(expression.split(/([*\/]|\b\s*-|\b\s*\+)/g));
```

##[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oFqRJm/1)

---

From *[Wiktor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801602/split-an-arithmetic-expression-with-a-regex/43801821#comment74643433_43801821)*, here is an improvement accepting parenthesis

```js
var expression = "-1 * -0.8 / (5 - 5)";
console.log(expression.split(/([*\/()]|\b\s*[-+])/g));
```

##[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/q0vFNN/1)

Comment: `.split(/([*/()]|\b\s*[-+])/).filter(Boolean))` is better. Also, you do not need the global modifier, `split` regex finds all matching strings and splits against them by default.